# (android IM app coded by asmack) roster.createEntry throws internal server error (500) exception

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I'm writing an IM APP using asmack.jar.After I connected the server and logined successfully,I wanna creatEntry as it.

`Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
roster.createEntry("g1_menber2@snake.openfired.com", "nickname",null);`

But it throws XMPPException that the message noted that"internal-server-error(500)".I have searched many times for this problem but there is no answser.
I do hope that you can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should go in openfire plugin field ->Available plugin->Add user import export plugin